# Пишу правильные пароли к подписному key, но пишет что неправильные

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, google-play

Только что создал key для подписи приложения, подписанный apk успешно родился.
Пробую второй раз, ничего не меняя, пишет: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key GBDG from store "C:******": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Таким же ключом хотел подписать бета версию приложения, но ошибка такая же

Comment: а срок действия ключа нормальный был выставлен? Или 10 секунд каких-нибудь?

Comment: @pavel , 25 дней